# How to produce Theil's U with package forecast 2.16 in R? 

Tags: r, forecasting, goodness-of-fit

I do not know why package forecast 2.16 in R does not produce Theil's U?
I really appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 14):

It does. Use the `accuracy()` command.

**Update:** here is an example.

```
library(forecast)
x <- EuStockMarkets[1:200,1]
f <- EuStockMarkets[201:300,1]
fit1 <- ses(x,h=100)
accuracy(fit1,f)
        ME       RMSE        MAE        MPE       MAPE       MASE       ACF1  Theil's U 
 0.8065983 78.1801986 63.2728352 -0.1725009  3.7876802  7.0619776  0.9586859  6.6120277
```

If you want the *in-sample* value of U (which is of limited value), the following will work:

```
fpe <- fit1$fitted[2:200]/x[1:199] - 1
ape <- x[2:200]/x[1:199] - 1
U <- sqrt(sum((fpe - ape)^2)/sum(ape^2))
```

Comment: @mohamed, (+1) nice to hear from the author of the function ^__^ From `example(accuracy)` it seems that x should be supplemnented first to see Theil's U and ACF1 see you do use `forecasterrors()` if `!missing(x)`. I think, for dr.Abed it is not intuitively clear.

Comment: I've added an example. If `x` is omitted, only in-sample results can be computed as explained in the help function. It would be possible to add an in-sample version of Theil's U as shown in the example, but I've never needed it and I can't imagine why anyone else would. But I can add it to the next version if it is useful to someone.

Comment: Hmmm, but Theil's U should be a ratio falling somewhere between 0 and 1?

Comment: Why? It is a ratio of MSE values. There's no reason why the numerator should be smaller than the denominator.

Comment: The current forecast's `accuracy()` (version 7.1) doesn't print Theil's U any longer.

Comment: @scai: That may have been a transient bug. `forecast` 8.2 prints Theil's U again.